# Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): OperationalError: incomplete input

Tags: python, tkinter

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "CRUD_guiado.py", line 69, in leer
    miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID=" + miId.get())
OperationalError: incomplete input
```

Seems i'm having a problem in my code I can't really see what i'm doing wrong please some help with it. As I can tell probably i got a an error with the format and not with the code itself, but probably im just guessing.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

#---------------------funciones---------------------------------------

def conexionBBDD():

    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Usuarios")

    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

    try:

        miCursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE DATOSUSUARIOS(
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            NOMBRE_USUARIO VARCHAR(50),
            PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
            APELLIDO VARCHAR(10),
            DIRECCION VARCHAR(50),
            COMENTARIOS VARCHAR(100))
            ''')

        messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "BBDD creada con exito")

    except:
    
        messagebox.showwarning("Atencion,", "La BBDD ya existe")

def salirAplicacion():

    valor=messagebox.askquestion("Salir", "Deseas salir de la aplicacion?")

    if valor=="yes":
        root.destroy()

def limpiarCampos():

    miNombre.set("")
    miId.set("")
    miApellido.set("")
    miDireccion.set("")
    miPass.set("")
    textoComentario.delete(1.0, END)

def crear():
    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Usarios")

    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

    miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATOSUSUARIOS VALUES(NULL, '" + miNombre.get() +
        "','" + miPass.get() + 
        "','" + miApellido.get() +
        "','" + miDireccion.get() +
        "','" + textoComentario.get("1.0", END) + "')")

    miConexion.commit()

    messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Registro insertado con exito")


def leer():

    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Usarios")

    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

    miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID=" + miId.get())

    elUsuario=miCursor.fetchall()

    for usuario in elUsuario:

        miId.set(usuario[0])
        miNombre.set(usuario[1])
        miPass.set(usuario[2])
        miApellido.set(usuario[3])
        miDireccion.set(usuario[4])
        textoComentario.insert(1.0, usuario[5])

    miConexion.commit() 

def actualizar():
    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Usarios")

    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

    miCursor.execute("UPDATE DATOSUSUARIOS SET NOMBRE_USUARIO='" + miNombre.get() +
        "', PASSWORD='" + miPass.get() +
        "', APELLIDO='" + miApellido.get() +
        "', DIRECCION='" + miDireccion.get() +
        "', COMENTARIOS='" + textoComentario.get("1.0", END) +
        "' WHERE ID=" + miId.get())


    miConexion.commit()

    messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Registro actualizado con exito")


def eliminar():

    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Usarios")

    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

    miCursor.execute("DELETE FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID=" + miId.get())

    miConexion.commit()

    messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Registro eliminado con exito")


root=Tk()

barraMenu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barraMenu, width=300, height=300)

bbddMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
bbddMenu.add_command(label="Conectar", command=conexionBBDD)
bbddMenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=salirAplicacion)

borrarMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
borrarMenu.add_command(label="Borrar campo", command=limpiarCampos)

crudMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
crudMenu.add_command(label="Crear", command=crear)
crudMenu.add_command(label="Leer", command=leer)
crudMenu.add_command(label="Actualizar", command=actualizar)
crudMenu.add_command(label="Borrar", command=eliminar)

ayudaMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
ayudaMenu.add_command(label="Licencia")
ayudaMenu.add_command(label="Acerca de")

barraMenu.add_cascade(label="BBDD", menu=bbddMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Borrar", menu=borrarMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="CRUD", menu=crudMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=ayudaMenu)

#----------------------comienzo de campos-------------------------------

miFrame=Frame(root)
miFrame.pack()

miId=StringVar()
miNombre=StringVar()
miApellido=StringVar()
miPass=StringVar()
miDireccion=StringVar()

cuadroId=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=miId)
cuadroId.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=miNombre)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroNombre.config(fg="red", justify="right")

cuadroPass=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=miPass)
cuadroPass.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroPass.config(show="*")

cuadroApellido=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=miApellido)
cuadroApellido.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

cuadroDireccion=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=miDireccion)
cuadroDireccion.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

textoComentario=Text(miFrame, width=16, height=5)
textoComentario.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
scrollVert=Scrollbar(miFrame, command=textoComentario.yview)
scrollVert.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="nsew")

textoComentario.config(yscrollcommand=scrollVert.set)

#------------------------aqui comienzan los label------------------------

idLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Id:")
idLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

nombreLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre:")
nombreLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

passLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Password:")
passLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

apellidoLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Apellido:")
apellidoLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

direccionLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Direccion:")
direccionLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

comentariosLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Comentarios:")
comentariosLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

#-----------------------aqui los botones----------------------------------

miFrame2=Frame(root)
miFrame2.pack()

botonCrear=Button(miFrame2, text="Crear", command=crear)
botonCrear.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

botonLeer=Button(miFrame2, text="Leer", command=leer)
botonLeer.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

botonActualizar=Button(miFrame2, text="Actualizar", command=actualizar)
botonActualizar.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

botonBorrar=Button(miFrame2, text="Borrar", command=eliminar)
botonBorrar.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)







root.mainloop()
```

So if you can share a little bit of wisdom prob I will get to work it in an instant with your help

Comment: keep in mind, the efficient and safe way of inserting into table is either by parameters or formatted string

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use:

```
miCursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID='{miId.get()}'")
```

Comment: Hi Kevin thanks for your answer. I just change the line but now it tells me something totally different                                                                                                                          `miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID='{miId.get()}'")
OperationalError: no such table: DATOSUSUARIOS` the problem is that the database is already created and it's at the same folder as the project prob something more about it